# how to create association in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Model user

```
...
        city_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true
        },
...
```

City model:

```
...
     const CitySchema = sequelize.define('city', {...});
...
```

define the association

```
db.user.hasOne(db.city, { foreignKey: 'id' })
db.city.belongsTo(db.user, { foreignKey: 'id', targetKey: 'city_id', as: 'city_data' })
```

what I received

```
Executing (default): SELECT count(`user`.`id`) AS `count` FROM `users` AS `user` LEFT OUTER JOIN `cities` AS `city` ON `user`.`id` = `city`.`id` WHERE `user`.`status` = 1;
```

but the expectation is:

```
Executing (default): SELECT count(`user`.`id`) AS `count` FROM `users` AS `user` LEFT OUTER JOIN `cities` AS `city` ON `user`.`city_id` = `city`.`id` WHERE `user`.`status` = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use slightly different association methods.

The hasOne() association method is for One-to-One associations. It creates a foreign key on the TARGET model (In the case of db.user.hasOne(db.city), CITY is the target model and Sequelize will create/expect a userId column in the city table). Many users should be able to be associated to the same city, so the association we want here is a One-to-Many.

`db.user.belongsTo(db.city)`

`db.city.hasMany(db.user)`

Add additional parameters as the second argument to each of these association methods as necessary.